# Solve teardrop equation for x

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given a teardrop:

$y = (1 - x^2)^m [\frac{(1 - x)}{2}]^{n/2}$

on the $x$ domain $[-1, 1]$, can someone suggest a solution for $x$ in terms of $y$, $m$ and $n$?

Comment: For all m and n, it looks like x=-1 and x=1 is a solution for x? This is just a suggestion.

Comment: That is true for $y = 0$.  But I am not trying to solve for $y = 0$.  For a given $y$ (where $0 < y < 1$) I want to find $x$ (and I know there will be two values).

Comment: I'm not all that hopeful - SageMath can solve it numerically but not exactly, so I might have to put up with a numerical solution.